# Cocoapods giving error on after updating Mac OS catalina

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, cocoapods

I have updated the Mac OS to Catalina 10.15.6. Now, when I try to install pods in Xcode project it gives following errors. I searched a lot over but could not find any working solution.
Here is log:

```
 pod install
Traceback (most recent call last):
    18: from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
    17: from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    16: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    15: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    14: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    13: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:46:in `run'
    12: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:150:in `verify_podfile_exists!'
    11: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:200:in `podfile'
    10: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:221:in `podfile_path'
     9: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:161:in `installation_root'
     8: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:274:in `normalize'
     7: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:136:in `decompose'
     6: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:136:in `inject'
     5: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:136:in `each'
     4: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:147:in `block in decompose'
     3: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:326:in `codepoints'
     2: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:336:in `load'
     1: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:336:in `open'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:336:in `initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/values/unicode_tables.dat (Errno::ENOENT)
```

Comment: Run `sudo gem update`